# Java - get value from equivalent key in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

For this code:

```
    //...
    System.out.println(Main.getCurrentPage().getDots()); //Type: ConcurrentHashMap<Point,String>
    System.out.println(mdp.getActivePoint()); //Type: Point
    System.out.println(Main.getRealCurrentPage().getDots().get(mdp.getActivePoint())); //Type: String
    //...
```

I get this output:

```
{java.awt.Point[x=278,y=354]=A1, java.awt.Point[x=542,y=370]=A1}
java.awt.Point[x=278,y=354]
null
```

I don't understand why the third line of this output isn't

```
A1
```

because the point printed in the second line of output is contained in the keyset of the map.

I thought it was because they're not being treated as the same object/reference for some reason, so I made a class that extends ConcurrentHashMap:

```
public class GoodCHashMap<K,V> extends ConcurrentHashMap<K,V>{

    public GoodCHashMap(){
        super();
    }

    public GoodCHashMap(GoodCHashMap<K,V> m){
        super(m);
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key){
        if(key instanceof Point){
            //System.out.println("!!!! hit");
            Point point = (Point) key;
            for(Object o : keySet()){
                Point p = (Point) o;
                if(point.x == p.x && point.y == p.y){
                    //System.out.println("This was a thing");
                    return super.get(p);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }else{
            return super.get(key);
        }
    }
}
```

This is designed so that if a Point is passed in to the get method, it iterates through its own keySet and, if a Point there has the same coordinates as the argument, it uses the Point from the keyset in the default ConcurrentHashMap get method. However, this too fails.

Can anyone help me understand and overcome this behavior?

Comment: Also, I checked the hashcode between the point in the map and the point i pass in to the get method, and they are identical.

Comment: What does the `equals` method of the `Point` class look like? Since you might check for the correct Point content, it doesn't mean that `super.get(p)` is also finding the correct key.

Comment: @n247s Point is from java.awt. According to openjdk, the equals method is `public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Point) {
            Point pt = (Point)obj;
            return (x == pt.x) && (y == pt.y);
        }
        return super.equals(obj);
    }` which is what i want.

Comment: I see, in that case you propably should start debugging to see where things go different from what you expect. (Ps. If the `equals` method of the Point object provide the desired compairison behavior, you dont really need a custom map inplementation, it only means more room for error.) Also when you are gonna debug try both your custum Map and the `ConcurrentHashMap` to see if there is any difference